# How to search with comma separated values in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a string comnid='1,2,3' and in need to find the rows with these id
eg:

i have a table like this

```
colour     comnid
----------------------
black       1
blue        2
green       3
yellow      4
```

and i need to return the rows which comnid are 1,2,3

Comment: The `IN` query clause is probably what you're after.  [https://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-in.aspx/#:~:text=Introduction%20to%20the%20MySQL%20IN,value2'%2C...)%3B](See here.)

Comment: `WHERE FIND_IN_SET(colors_table.comnid, @comnid)`

Comment: @fancyPants The IN clause accepts comma separated values, so I doubt you do.  But I also wasn't answering the question in full; just providing a link that will almost certainly put the user in the right direction if they just didn't know what to search for.

Answer (score 1):

Would be `... WHERE comnid IN(1,2,3)`

Please note that a query may be vulnerable to `sql injections`. You need to prepare it correctly, depending of what support language / lib you are using. In `PHP` would use function `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.

Comment: `'1,2,3'` is ONE string literal - it cannot be used by such way without dynamic SQL usage. Using your method you'll obtain `WHERE comnid IN('1,2,3')` which will not act as needed.

Comment: yeah, he got to split it in main code (whatever language is that), or use your comment as an answer...

Comment: Not needed - FIND_IN_SET() is designed specially for to test a value against CSV values list string literal.

Comment: As I said. For example `PHP` `explode()` is much more effective than `FIND_IN_SET()`, and maybe he got those values in array already. My answer is not invalid.

Comment: I do not see `[php]` tag - so OP needs in solution using pure MySQL-specific SQL.

Comment: You (almost) never use pure MySQL... my answer just gives the optimal (by performance) solution. No need to `-1` it. Please note that it's a newcomer. `FIND_IN_SET` is not optimal (in performance), and not needed to be used in 99% of cases. Doesn't mean it's a bad answer, just giving an alternative.

Comment: from main code i got  one comma seperated string ,FIND_IN_SET() only return the position .i need whole rows with these id.

Comment: *my answer just gives the optimal (by performance) solution* Imagine that OP have no PHP - for example, he uses C# or VBA/ADODB... do you still claim that your method is optimal in this case? install PHP and integrate it into the project...

Comment: I C# exploding string to array is even faster :) Not sure about VBA. I would let the op to decide if it was helpful. Seriously don't think I deserved `-1`. Would give a benchmark of `FIND_IN_SET` vs `IN` but i don't have time for this.

Comment: *Seriously don't think I deserved `-1`* - show the code which will convert single string literal to integer values list in the query - and I'll remove downvote. Now your answer seems to be non-applicable. PS. Be ready to downvotes from another users who does not like direct query building due to possible injection.

Comment: Please note that `FIND_IN_SET` doesn't even use `INDEXES`. It's really slow. About injection, I totally agree... but OP didn't give a language that he uses, so hard to comment that.

Comment: Speaking about performance I'd suggest parsing on MySQL side using JSON_TABLE().

Comment: I just tested it with 1 000 000 records, with `IN()` it took `0.46s` with `FIND_IN_SET` it took `12.62s`. The difference is huge. Anyway I added a note about `sql injection`. Please note that records were indexed.

Comment: Tested on Raspberry Pi 3 on MariaDB 10.3.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE colours_table
> SELECT 'black'   colour,    1 comnid UNION ALL
> SELECT 'blue'          ,    2        UNION ALL
> SELECT 'green'         ,    3        UNION ALL
> SELECT 'yellow'        ,    4        ;
>
> SELECT * FROM colours_table;
> ```
>
> ```
> colour | comnid
> :----- | -----:
> black  |      1
> blue   |      2
> green  |      3
> yellow |      4
> ```

> ```
> SET @comnid = '1,2,3';
>
> SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(colour)
> FROM colours_table
> WHERE FIND_IN_SET(comnid, @comnid);
> ```
>
> ```
> | GROUP_CONCAT(colour) |
> | :------------------- |
> | black,blue,green     |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=734f1ca8a16adc8b0562459f5d1e7afe)*

If you need in separate rows then simply do not use GROUP_CONCAT:

```sql
SELECT colour
FROM colours_table
WHERE FIND_IN_SET(comnid, @comnid);
```